# Get the logging path from a Logger?

Tags: logging, groovy, logback, slf4j

Using the `Logger` magically produced in Groovy by using the @Slf4j annotation, is there any way to find out the actual path where the logging is taking place?

The conventional way (only way?) of configuring this logger is to use an XML config file, `logback.xml` in my case. This contains the path. One way to obtain the path would therefore be to analyse this XML file.

But it occurs to me that this XML file is, by definition, used to configure some object held ... somewhere. This path detail does not appear to accessible from the `org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.util.Logger class`. I don't know exactly how the logback classes relate to this Logger class, but there are [lots of classes for logback](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/index.html), so it might just be possible to find this info.

Anyone know?

Comment: "is there any way to find out the actual path where the logging is taking place" - Loggers have appenders associated with them and some appenders might have a path associated with them but some don't, so not all loggers have a path associated with them.  For example, if you had a logger associated with only 1 appender and that appender was writing to stdout, there would be no path.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get a handle on a Groovy Logger's appender, in general?

Comment: You can retrieve an appender by name using the `getAppender(String)` method on the `Logger`.  See http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.html#getAppender(java.lang.String).